# strange resource reference location in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my personal rails project and I'm still learning a lot of things day by day.
This time, I got a strange behaviour for that the HTML tag generated content has been placed in strange locations.

Take below for example:

below is the ERB from my web application home page.

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
```

and when the output has been generated by rails, I view the source page, and the output appears to be as below.

```
 <img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/assets/logo.png" />
```

My question is "how can that the generated tag look for the reference to the image file in /assets/logo.png instead of the expected /images/logo.png?"

Any mistake I could have made in my configuration?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the new asset pipeline in action:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html